# Check if multiple user ids are friends with a particular person

Tags: facebook-graph-api, batch-file

I want to know which people in a list of people are friends with this user.  Is there a graph api call that can return the subset of ids that is the user's friends?  I've tried:

/me/friends/?ids=xxxxx,xxxx

I know I can use a batch call an do something like this:

/me/friends/xxxx
/me/friends/xxxxx

but it would be nice to do it in one call.

Answer (score 2):

There wasn't an easy way to do this with the graph api, but I was able to do it with an FQL query:

```
query = '{
"are_friends":"SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()+and+uid2+in('+people_array.join()+')+limit+10",
"friend_meta":"SELECT+uid,first_name,last_name,name,pic_square+FROM+user+where+uid+in(SELECT+uid2+FROM+%23are_friends)"}'
```

The friend_meta json object in the result will have all the meta info you are looking for.  It's one call, and more efficient and cleaner than the batch calls.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the mutualfriends option?

```
me/mutualfriends/xxxxx
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Comment: It looks like the parameter for mutual friends two users and finds their intersection.  It works great for that, but I was looking for an easy way to check if a bunch of users are a particular user's friend.